# Why my socket connection is breaking after 2 mins after upgrading websocket-jetty-server from 9.4.48.v20220622 to 11.0.12?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, java-websocket

websocket-jetty-server 11.0.12 socket connection is breaking after 2 mins

I am using websocket-jetty-server version 11.0.12 to use websocket.
I wanted to use the java verion 17 so I upgraded websocket-jetty-server from 9.4.48.v20220622 to 11.0.12
Now, my socket connection is breaking after 2 mins and getting the below error message

org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.exceptions.WebSocketTimeoutException: Connection Idle Timeout

Strange thing is, it is working fine on my local Ubuntu VM but failing on RHEL machine.

Comment: which way are you configuring the idleTimeout?

Comment: I have used this in configure method factory.setIdleTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(0));

Comment: I have also checked with factory.setIdleTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(3600000));

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared some of your code in the question or a simple reproducer.

Comment: It's resolved now. The issue was with the entropy. Installed haveged service and it started working. Thank you for your time.